# How to correct SQL Syntax Error for WITH clause?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, left-join, impala, with-statement

Dealing with a syntax error (Encountered: SELECT, Expected: CROSS, FROM, GROUP,...) when trying to SELECT **t1.***. The middle of my code runs without error (table **t1**) but when trying to select table **t1**, I get an error.

The code:

```
with test as (
   select * from (
      select id, name, department, org, time, reporttime, scheduled_time, address
     ,row_number() over (partition by id order by time desc, reporttime desc, scheduled_time desc) AS row_rank 
     from table1
     ) t1
--syntax error below
select t1.* where row_rank =1 
)

select t1.*, t2.id, t2.new_org, t2.date
from test
left outer join table2 as t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.new_org != "A"
```

Is there a way around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the info that identifies as table2, but Your error is a result of how you set up your CTE.  Here's the way I would do it:

```
with t1 as (
   select * 
      select id, name, department, org, time, reporttime, scheduled_time, address
     ,row_number() over (partition by id order by time desc, reporttime desc, scheduled_time desc) AS row_rank 
     from table1
), test as (
select t1.* where row_rank =1 
)

select test.*, t2.id, t2.new_org, t2.date
from test
left outer join table2 as t2
     on test.id = t2.id
where t2.new_org != "A"
```